# Discord.js - Getting users last activity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to find out if its possible to get the time/information of users last activity retrospectively using `discord.js`

Say I have something like

```
  client.guilds.find('id', 'SERVER ID').fetchMembers().then(members => {
        const role = members.roles.find('name', 'Newbies')

        role.members.forEach(member => {
              console.log(member.user.lastMessage) // null
        })
  })
```

Unless the member has posted, since the client is listening, the lastMessage is always null.

Is there a way to find the last activity? or a workaround, like a query to return all the users messages, which I can then take the most recent one from?

Effectively I want to know what date/time the user last posted so we can monitor non-contributing accounts.

Thanks

Comment: You have to fetch every messages of every TextChannels to get every message of the guild then filtering to get the last message from a member, you can also sort by timestamps of messages and get the first one

Answer (score 3):

After looking thought the documentation I didn't find something neither so I came up with a manual search function.

Basically, it will scan every channels until finding a message from X user, or the end of the messages in the channel. It then compare the last messages of the users from every channels and print the last one.

It can be very long if the user hasn't write since a long time. Of course, you have to check `lastMessage` before trying this.

I would add a time limit maybe. Because if you have thousand of messages, the function will run eternally.

You can stop the function if the last message found is in the accepted time to not be kick/do whatever.

I made the search stop if the first message found in the pack of fetched messaged is older than the ban limit, however, if the first message is not older, remember that it means for the other, so we still need to check them (it can be avoided by checking the last message of the pack as well).

```js
async function fetchMessageUser(chan, id, res) {
  let option = {};
  if (typeof res !== 'undefined'){
    option = {before: res.id};
  }
  return await chan.fetchMessages(option)
      .then(async msgs => {
    if (msgs.size === 0){
      return {continue: false, found: false};
    };
    if ((Date.now() - (msgs.first().createdTimestamp)) > 86400000 ) { // 1 day
      return {continue: false, found: false};
    }
    let msgByAuthor = msgs.find(msg => {
      return msg.author.id === id;
    });
    if (msgByAuthor === null){
      return {continue: true, id: msgs.last().id};
    } else {
      return {continue: false, found: true, timestamp: msgByAuthor.createdTimestamp};
    }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('ERR>>', err));
}


client.on('message', async (msg) => {
  let timestamp = [];
  for (let [id, chan] of msg.guild.channels){
    if (chan.type !== 'text'){ continue; }
    let id = '587692527826763788'; // id of the user, here a non verified account
    let res;
    do {
      res = await fetchMessageUser(chan, id, res);
    } while(res.continue);
    if (res.found) {
      timestamp.push(res.timestamp);
    }
  }
  console.log(timestamp);
  let first = timestamp.sort((a,b) => (b-a))[0];
  console.log(new Date(first));
});
```

A better variant would be to run it for an array of users, checking all 50 last messages from every channel, and associating each users with his most recent messages if he wrote one, and doing this until all the messages in all the channels are too old to avoid a kick/whatever. And then do something for all the users who don't have an associated messages.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is one of Discord's built in features, namely: pruning. This feature will grab inactive members and lets you kick them. Luckily, discord.js has an API call for it and even lets you get the number of members first without actually kicking them by setting the `dry` parameter to `true`. The feature will also allow you to specify the amount of days a user has to be inactive.

Have a look at the docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=pruneMembers

Hope that helps out!

Comment: This is useful to know thanks, however I was simplifying the use case to be honest, so ideally would still want to find a way to get the user space last message regardless

Comment: Additionally this seems to only target users who have not been seen, rather than those who have not been contributing. E.g. those who are reading daily, but not posting would completely bypass this functionality

Comment: I see, in that case the prune feature would be too simple for what you want to achieve; listening and keeping track of the date and time people send messages would be the only way, I'm afraid.

Comment: For info, there is a built-in functionality to prune members: https://support.discord.com/hc/articles/213507137