# How to get the last message sent by a member?

Tags: discord.js

```
  let usr = message.mentions.members.first()
  message.channel.send("Kullanıcı son mesajı:" + usr.lastMessage.url)
```

I want to get the last message sent by the mentioned user.
But I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastMessage' of undefined

Comment: `usr` is undefined so your lookup failed. That is, you're trying to get the property `lastMessage` from nothing.  Also, your question may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087758/discord-js-getting-users-last-activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to get guild member fist.

```
  let usr = message.guild.member(message.mentions.members.first())
  if(usr) {
    message.channel.send("Kullanıcı son mesajı:" + usr.lastMessage.url)
  }
```

**V2**

```
  let usr = message.guild.member(message.mentions.members.first())
  if(usr) {
    if(usr.lastMessage !== null) {
    message.channel.send("Kullanıcı son mesajı:" + usr.lastMessage.url)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it's not working, error is same. 
```TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of null```

Comment: Hmm, so user don`t have messages :)
Check the v2 code