# is it possible to collect messages sent in the past by a user with Discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I wanted to create a Discord bot using Discord.js. One of the main feature of this bot is to check which was the last message sent by a user (on the entire server if possible) and collect the message's informations (the date, the content...). But a faced several difficulties trying to implement this feature.

The main difficulty i've faced is that the id of the last message sent by a user could be null if the user has not sent a message since the last restart of the bot. The bot only detects the messages sent after its last restart.

I thought the discord's Message Collector coul solve my problem, so I tried something like this :

```
const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel,
    message => message.author.equals(user),
    {max: 1, time: 10000}
);

collector.on('collect', (m, collector) => {
    lastMessage = console.log('Collected', m)
})
```

This is a very simple collector in order to discover message collectors.
The collector only collects messages that have not yet been sent. However, I want to collect the messages that have already been sent

So i want to know is there is a solution to my problem using Discord.js

Comment: This is the first problem I had to face. This method returns null if the user mentionned (in the command) hasn't send a message since the bot's last restart. But I want my bot to return the mentionned user's last message even if this message has been sent after the bot's last restart...

Comment: I've checked the `GuildMember.lastMessage` property, and it returns null when I check someone's last message, even if this account already sent a message. As I see, this property depends on when the bot's listening has started :/

This is the same problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087758/discord-js-getting-users-last-activity (I'll check this solution)

Comment: Ah I see now, did some searching and it seems it doesn't work for messages send before the bot got online. My appologies

Comment: No problem. I guess I'll have to find an other solution ! Thanks for your help !